# mknod() not creating named pipe

Tags: linux, system-calls, unlink, mknod

I'm trying to create a FIFO named pipe using the mknod() command:

```
int main() {
char* file="pipe.txt";
int state;
state = mknod(file, S_IFIFO & 0777, 0);
printf("%d",state);
return 0;
}
```

But the file is not created in my current directory. I tried listing it by `ls -l` . State returns -1.

I found similar questions here and on other sites and I've tried the solution that most suggested:

```
int main() {
char* file="pipe.txt";
int state;
unlink(file);
state = mknod(file, S_IFIFO & 0777, 0);
printf("%d",state);
return 0;
}
```

This made no difference though and the error remains. Am I doing something wrong here or is there some sort of system intervention which is causing this problem?

Help.. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't just `printf(state)`.  `state` is an `int`.  You would need `printf("%d\n", state)`.

Comment: oh yes... just a typing mistake. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `&` to set the file type instead of `|`.  From the docs:

> The  file type for path is OR'ed into the mode argument, and the
>   application shall select one of the following symbolic
>   constants...

Try this:

```
state = mknod(file, S_IFIFO | 0777, 0);
```

Because this works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main() {
    char* file="pipe.txt";
    int state;
    unlink(file);
    state = mknod(file, S_IFIFO | 0777, 0);
    printf("state %d\n", state);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile it:

```
gcc -o fifo fifo.c
```

Run it:

```
$ strace -e trace=mknod ./fifo
mknod("pipe.txt", S_IFIFO|0777)         = 0
state 0
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

See the result:

```
$ ls -l pipe.txt
prwxrwxr-x. 1 lars lars 0 Jul 16 12:54 pipe.txt
```

Comment: It's not clear why you've changed it to something that is obviously incorrect based on the documentation.  ANDing the value with the mode is just going to result in `0`, which will create a normal file with no permissions.

Comment: I've updated this answer with the behavior I see on my system.

Comment: Hey! that worked. Thanks so much.. But I wonder why my program won't work :(.. Are all the above header files needed for the program??

Comment: I just used the `#include`'s the man page for `mknod` said to use.  That seems like the best course of action.  If I remove everything other than `#include <fcntl.h>` it still seems to work, although there are of course a number of warnings.